# External sqlite db file from sdcard in android

Tags: android, memory, sqlite

I just searched for the same but didn't get the answers. What I have is a `db` file which is around `100MB`. I have saved the `db` file in `sdcard` .

Through this `db` file I'm going to populate the contents for the android app. I can read the db file using like below.

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/Your_db_File.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase  db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
```

What I'm concerned is about the memory. I have read like in `assets` it has some memory limitations. I'm just worried like will `100MB` of db file in sdcard or external memory is a harm or is it OK to have `100MB` db file? Or is there any limitations for sqlite db file in external storage as well? Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite itself has no problem with 100mb databases, as you can see [here](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) it can handle upwards of 140TB in a single database file.

As for Android, each system has different constraints since various providers can decide how much physical memory to install along with which apps run at startup, etc.

I imagine there should be little problem with a 100mb database since that is effectively quite small, however the only real way to know would be to test it on a variety of target devices in a variety of scenarios.